# A weak convergence in Sobolev space.

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $u \in C^0([0,T], H^{s-1}(\Bbb R^n)).  $ Let $\{t_n \}  \subset [0,T]$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} t_n = t_0$. Let $ u(t_n ) \to u(t_0) $ in the Sobolev space $H^{s-1} ( \Bbb R^n )$ for $s = 1,2, \cdots$. Assume $ \| u(t_n ) \|_{H^{s} (\Bbb R^n)} \leqslant R < \infty $ for all $n$.

Then how can we find a subsequence $\{t_k \}$ of $\{ t_n \}$ such that $u(t_k ) \to u(t_0) \;weakly$  in $H^s$ ?

Comment: Alaoglu's theorem.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you. Then the assumption "$u(t_n) \to u(t_0)$ in the Sobolev space $H^{s−1}$ for $s=1,2,⋯.$" needless? I think if just $ \| u (t_n ) \|_{H^s} \leqslant R$ then we can apply Alaoglu's theorem.

Comment: Alaoglu will guarantee that a subsequence converges weakly to *something*.  You'll need the $H^{s-1}$ convergence to show that the limit is in fact $u(t_0)$.

Comment: Actually, aren't you assuming $u : [0,T] \to H^s$ is continuous?  That would imply that $u(t_n) \to u(t_0)$ strongly in $H^s$; you don't need weak convergence or a subsequence.  Are you sure you wanted to assume that?

Comment: @NateEldredge Oh, sorry. Then the assumption $u \in C^0 ([0,T], H^s) $ should be changed to $ u \in C^0([0,T], H^{s-1})$.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  When you have the details worked out, you might like to post your own answer.